# What tools could I use on Ubuntu 16.04 to cut mp4 files into several clips?

Tags: mp4

I am trying to cut a long video into several small pieces. Any recommended tools can do the task?

Comment: @DavidFoerster IMHO - This seems to be specific to cutting into segments as opposed to a general video editing question..

Comment: @ElderGeek video editing software is generally used to cut portions of video and move them around. Exporting clips is just one extra step.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I would agree that cutting and moving is part of video editing. Adding and adjusting sound tracks is also a part. The accepted answer here for cutting a video into clips is better suited to the particular question posed than any of the others in the generic answer marked as a duplicate. Installing a full blown video editing suite seems overkill for the task at hand since `ffmpeg` accurately handles timecodes with the -ss and -t switches. I don't believe that any of the video editing suites is better suited to this task.

Comment: Voting to reopen as I don't see this task as well suited to the video editing suites in th marked duplicate answer.

Comment: In that case, the question would be too broad imo @elder

Comment: Thanks for your editing and helped me solved the problem. Elder Geek :)

Comment: @Zacharee1 actually, this question is far more narrow than the question you voted as a duplicate! Perhaps reading them again would provide clarity.

Comment: @r0ng Glad to help!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I found ffmpeg could do the task. 
To install the ffmpeg
`sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`
To copy a specific short duration from the video file.

`ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -ss 00:01:52 -c copy -t 00:00:10 output.mp4`

- -i:input file. The file name of the original video clip.
- -ss:start timestamp. In my case I tried to copy the new video from the original video started after 1 minute and 52 seconds.
- -t:indicating the duration of the new video clip, in my case, 10 seconds.
- Not sure parameter -c for, maybe the action? If some1 knows, let me know plz.

---

Reference:
- [Cut video by using ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video)
- [ffmpeg seeking](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking) in subsection [cut small sections]

Comment: -c indicates the codec to use (in this case copy as is without re-encoding)

Comment: For me it created audio mp4 file.

Comment: Thanks, but any solution for some fraction of a second? -ss 00:00:07:35 is invalid.

Comment: @SYK you can type it like 00:00:07.35

Answer (score 4):

[Kdenlive](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kdenlive&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all), a non-linear video editor.

Install with:

```
$ sudo apt install kdenlive
```

You can see others by running `Ubuntu Software` and typing `video editor` in the search area.

Answer (score 3):

**Avidemux** is good for quickly cutting video.  Despite the name, it handles MPEG-4 video standards fine (as well as any other modern format like MKV).

It's **not** a non-linear editor, meaning that once you've made some cuts you can't go back and change earlier ones, and you can't re-order segments or insert new segments (although you can join videos by adding new clips *at the end*).  It's great for simple tasks like trimming the start and end and maybe commercial breaks.

It can do what you want without issues - just select the segment to output, export it, then select the next part, and so on.  If your selections fall on GOP boundaries (ie I-frames) then you can do it losslessly - without re-encoding, using "copy" as the video/audio codecs.

Comment: :+1: Editing reminds me of VirtualDub from Windows era